# Stop cursor blinking in IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle, caret, blink

Python beginner here.
Blinking cursors in interfaces really distract me and the one in Idle doesn't have the option to stop blinking.

I've found this https://bugs.python.org/issue4630 which shows how to modify 2 lines of code in the idlelib/EditorWindow.py file to stop the cursor from blinking.
But it is either for version 2.6 or 3.
I currently use 2.7 and obviously the code is not the same nor located at the same lines.

Could someone more savvy in this language please let me know where can I find the necessary lines and how to modify them so that I can have make this modification ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2.7 to 3.5, `Lib/idlelib/EditorWindow.py`, around line 185, or in 3.6+, `Lib/idlelib/editor.py`, currently around line 185 (but this may change), one can find

```
text_options = {
        'name': 'text',
        'padx': 5,
        'wrap': 'none',
        'highlightthickness': 0,
        'width': self.width,
        'height': idleConf.GetOption(
            'main', 'EditorWindow', 'height', type='int')}
```

Before the last line, insert

```
        'insertofftime': 0,
```

either on a new line or to the end of an existing line.  I tested this on both 2.7 and 3.6.

EDIT: For current 3.9+, on the top menu, select Options and Configure IDLE.  On the Settings dialog, select the Windows tab.  There is a "Cursor blink" checkbox on the third line.

Comment: whoo hoo !!! this works !
Thank you very much !

Just to clarify on 2.7 I found it on line 179 and inserted the code between 'width' and 'height'